# RecyclerView item with layout_weight=1

Tags: android

Resume:

I have a ChatActivity that's basic a RecyclerView. In my chat_row_layout, i have a horizontal LinearLayout (width = wrap_content) with 2 TextViews, one of then with layout_weight = 1.

My problem :

When scrolling the recycler, some of my views width get messed up because of the recycling.

Is there some way to fix that? Ex. Force the adapter to get the original view measures

Ps: sorry for the bad formating + lack of info (i'm on phone)

Comment: Can you post your chat_row_layout file? It would help to solve your problem